# Error using boost::bind

Tags: c++, templates, boost, generic-programming

Lets say I have an array of functions :

```
name::Function _actions[10];
```

The name::Function is just a wrapper for std::function:

```
class Function{
    public :
        std::function<void(float dt)> Function;

        void exec(float dt){


            Function(dt);
        }
};
```

And now I have a function to make it generic so it can bind any classes functions :

```
template<class T>
void bindFunction(int action,void (T::*function)(float) , T* classPtr)
{
    _actions[action] = boost::bind(&function, this, boost::placeholders::_1);
}
```

And want to use it inside a class that inherits this method (the base class is generic but I think it shouldn´t be a problem)

```
    DefaultMovableEntity()
    {
        bindFunction(1, &DefaultMovableEntity::func1, this);
    }

    void func1(float dt)
    {
        //Code
    }
```

However I keep getting erros :
[image]

What is the main problem? I thought im doing everything right. Thanks.

**Edit1**
After removing the & from the function and replacing this got following error:
[image]

Comment: Shot in the dark: try removing the `&` from `&function`?

Comment: Just currious; why `boost::bind` rather than `std::bind`?

Comment: remove `&` before `function` and replace `this` with `classPtr`.

Comment: C++03 with tr1 has `std::tr1::bind`, C++11 has `std::bind`, but it also has lambdas, which are more handy.

Comment: updated question with additional picture after the removal of the & and change of the pointer

Comment: @JesperJuhl Im used to it and remember that long time ago had some troubles with std::bind, so started using boost as it builds upon std::bind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

1. You can't assign your `bind` result to the array since your array member type is `Function`, not `std::function`.
2. You need to remove `&` as said before in comments.
3. Your member named `Function` is same as class name so compiler may think you are trying to call class constructor.

The following code should work:

```
class Function {
public:
    std::function<void(float)> func;

    void exec(float dt) {
        func(dt);
    }
};
```

and `bindFunction` code:

```
template<class T>
void bindFunction(int action, void (T::*function)(float), T* classPtr)
{
    _actions[action].func = boost::bind(function, classPtr, boost::placeholders::_1);
}
```

However I would suggest slight improvement of Function class so that it doesn't expose its members directly:

```
class Function
{
private:
    std::function<void(float)> func;

public:
    Function() = default;
    Function(std::function<void(float)> f) : func(f) { }

    void exec(float dt) {
        func(dt);
    }
};
```

And corresponding change of your `bindFunction`:

```
template<class T>
void bindFunction(int action, void (T::*function)(float), T* classPtr)
{
    _actions[action] = Function(boost::bind(function, classPtr, boost::placeholders::_1));
}
```

Comment: That was exactly the problem ! I totally forgot about the wrapper class and the fact im not assigning it to std::function. Just curious about your addition constructor with default keyword, why should I use it ?